# Fill ArrayList with sockets in constructor?

Tags: java, sockets, arraylist

I am currently trying to take an ArrayList and fill it with sockets using .add, when the socket is passed into the constructor. When i run the debug, it looks like there is only ever 1 socket filling the ArrayList, and no more, even though I've opened like 6 client threads.

**Server class**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    final int PORT = 8888;
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    System.out.println("Waiting...");

    while(true)
    {
        Socket s = server.accept();
        System.out.println("Client connected");
        Service service = new Service(s);
        Thread t = new Thread(service);
        t.start();
    }
```

**Service class**

```
 public class Service implements Runnable
{
private Socket s;
private Scanner in;
private PrintWriter out;
private ArrayList<Socket> sockets = new ArrayList<Socket>();

public Service(Socket aSocket)
{
    s = aSocket;
    sockets.add(s);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you create a new Service every loop => you will have 6 Service objects with one arrayList in each containing each objects socket. If you want your arrayList to contain all clients / sockets, you will have to have this list in your server class. Also it's rarely a good idea for your clients to know about all other clients. 
I also suggest putting in a Thread.sleep(100) in your main method (server), otherwise it will take up a lot of your precessing power.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    final int PORT = 8888;
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    System.out.println("Waiting...");
    private ArrayList<Socket> sockets = new ArrayList<Socket>();

    while(true)
    {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        Socket s = server.accept();
        System.out.println("Client connected");
        Service service = new Service(s);
        Thread t = new Thread(service);
        t.start();
        sockets.add(s);
    }
```